# CSS3 box shadow: both, outter and inner

Tags: css

Is it possible to create both an outer shadow for a 3D effect and an inner inset glow? I have a div with a lime green background that's on top of a blue div. So far, I have the following:

```
.greendiv{
   background:darkgreen;
   box-shadow: box-shadow: 10px -7px 15px darkgray;
   box-shadow: lightgreen 0px 0px 3px inset;
}
```

The actual colors are in #ffffff format. It seems that the second declaration cancels the first one. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You simply declare `box-shadow` once, and use both versions inside, separated with a comma:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-box-shadow

> The ‘box-shadow’ property attaches one or more drop-shadows to the box. The property is a comma-separated list of shadows, each specified by 2-4 length values, an optional color, and an optional ‘inset’ keyword.

So, for you:

```
.greendiv {
    background: darkgreen;
    box-shadow: 10px -7px 15px darkgray, lightgreen 0px 0px 3px inset;
}
```

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/JzsAh/

Comment: I had no idea you could use commas for multiple properties. What else does this work for? And how cross-browser compatible is it?

Comment: @tehlivi: It works in every browser that supports `box-shadow`. Another [example is `background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multiple_backgrounds) in CSS3.

Comment: @tehlivi: you can also do the same for transitions and animations etc, etc e.g. `transition: bottom 1s ease, left 3s ease;`